# Expected response code "250" but got code "550", with message "550-Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable 550 Sender address has null MX"

Tags: laravel, email, deployment, smtp, ionos

I have a Laravel 9.x site that I'm hosting on IONOS (shared-hosting).

In my site, I utilize mail a lot. So I'm sending mails to my customer frequently. While developing the system - I was using MailTrap.io - but for deployment, I need all the mails to go to my IONOS Mail Account i.e info@domain.com - for that, I need to use IONOS' Mail Configuration.

Following is my mail config (censoring out private info):

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.ionos.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=####@#######.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=################
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=#####@#######.com
```

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

This is the piece of manual documentation I got from IONOS' Dashboard:

[image]

How do I fix this? What is causing this issue? Like I mentioned before, all of it was working fine with MailTrap.io - so I'm really curious what am I doing wrong.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As per [ionos.com documentation](https://www.ionos.com/help/email/postmaster/smtp-error-messages-of-the-11-ionos-mail-servers/.)

> 550  Sender address has null MX

> The domain from which you send email has a configured No Service MX record (zero MX). The IONOS SMTP recipient rejects such emails

> Delete the No Service MX entry in the DNS settings of your domain. For more information about a No Service MX entry, see RFC 7505.

Comment: I think my issue falls under "550 requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable" - does it not?

Comment: @VenoM i think it's both, but having wrong MX entry in DNS config will lead to unverified mailbox error too.